# Set input as hyperlink in Angular forms

Tags: javascript, angular

As part of an application I am using angular forms to build there is the following input field:

```
        <igx-input-group>
          <input igxInput name="preamblesRef" id="preamblesRef"  type="text" formControlName="preamblesRef" [readonly]="!userEditable"
          inputValidationDirective [control]="libraryForm.controls['preamblesRef']"/>
          <label igxLabel for="preamblesRef">Preambles Reference</label>
        </igx-input-group>
```

What I am trying to do is check if the text within the field is a link, and if so add an anchor tag to it so that users can just click on the link and it will open the site in a new.

What I have done so far is:

```
  checkIfPreamblesIsLink(url: string) {
    const checkIfLink = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|(www\\.)?){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

if(checkIfLink.test(url)) {
    console.log("match");
    const test = document.getElementById('preamblesRef');
    const anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    const aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.setAttribute('href', url);
    test.appendChild(aTag);
    this.libraryForm.controls.preamblesRef.setValue(aTag.getAttribute('href'));
} else {
  console.log("not a match");
}
```

The regex seems to work fine and it's recognizing that it's a url. However, what I am struggling to do is convert the text within the input into a link. I have tried creating a new anchor tag, and whilst this does get created, the text itself within the input, is not affected and does not become a hyperlink. Where about am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I never left an answer for what I did for this, apologies. What I ended up going for was the following:

```
      <div id="editPreamblesInput" #editPreamblesRef #editPreamblesInput (mouseenter)="userEditable? displayPreamblesLink.show() : null" (mouseleave)="displayPreamblesLink.hide()">
        <input-validation>
          <igx-input-group>
            <input igxInput name="preamblesRef" id="preamblesRef" type="text" formControlName="preamblesRef" [readonly]="!userEditable"
            inputValidationDirective [control]="libraryForm.controls['preamblesRef']"/>
            <label igxLabel for="preamblesRef">Preambles Reference</label>
          </igx-input-group>
        </input-validation>

      <igx-action-strip #displayPreamblesLink [displayDensity]="displayDensity" class="action-strip" [hidden]="true">
          <igx-buttongroup class="buttons">
              <button igxButton type="button" *ngIf="preamblesIsUrl" (click)="showLink()">
                  <igx-icon>link</igx-icon>
              </button>
          </igx-buttongroup>
      </igx-action-strip>
      </div>

      <div id="linkPreamblesInput" class="highlight" #linkPreamblesRef (mouseenter)="userEditable && preamblesIsUrl? editPreambles.show() : null" (mouseleave)="editPreambles.hide()">
          <igx-input-group>
            <input igxInput name="preamblesRef" id="preamblesRef" type="text" [readonly]="true" value="{{preamblesUrl}}" (click)="openURL()"/>
            <label igxLabel for="preamblesRef">Preambles Reference</label>
          </igx-input-group>

        <igx-action-strip #editPreambles [displayDensity]="displayDensity" class="action-strip" [hidden]="true">
          <igx-buttongroup class="buttons">
              <button igxButton *ngIf="userEditable" type="button" (click)="showEditInput()">
                  <igx-icon>edit</igx-icon>
              </button>
          </igx-buttongroup>
      </igx-action-strip>
      </div>


 public checkIfPreamblesIsLink(url: string, setInputDisplay = true) {
  const checkIfLink = new RegExp(/^(?:https?):\/\/(?:[\w-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}(?:\/[^?\s]*)?(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[^\s]*)?$/i);

if(checkIfLink.test(url)) {
  this.preamblesIsUrl = true;
  if(setInputDisplay) {
    this.showLink();
  }
} else {
  this.preamblesIsUrl = false;
  if(setInputDisplay) {
    this.showEditInput();
  }
}
```

}

```
  public showEditInput() {
    this.preamblesInputRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    this.preamblesLinkRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }

  public showLink() {
    this.preamblesLinkRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    this.preamblesInputRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }

  public openURL() {
    window.open(this.preamblesUrl, '_blank').focus();
  }
```

This may not be the best solution but it does what I need it to do and is able to correctly check if what has been entered is indeed a link.

As you'll be able to see, there are 2 separate divs, and the one that appears is dependent on whether the input matches the regex or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PattrnValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator) to make angular validate control for you:

```js
        <igx-input-group>
          <input igxInput 
            name="preamblesRef" 
            id="preamblesRef"  
            type="text" 
            formControlName="preamblesRef" 
            [readonly]="!userEditable"
            inputValidationDirective                         
            [control]="libraryForm.controls['preamblesRef']"
            pattern="^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|(www\\.)?){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?"/>
          <!-- you can bind it from a controller field, this is just for example -->
          <label igxLabel for="preamblesRef">Preambles Reference</label>
        </igx-input-group>
```

Then you can add an `<a>` tag somewhere in your template and show it only if `preamblesRef` control is valid, e.g.:

```js
  <a *ngIf="preamblesRef.valid" [href]="preamblesRef.value">Link text</a>
```